# How to auto-import namespaces for whole PHP file in phpStorm?

Tags: php, netbeans, namespaces, ide, phpstorm

How can I do something like NetBeans does with "Fix Uses..." (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) in PHPStorm, so I can fix FCQN in my project files?

What I already found is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on class name, but how can I do it for whole file?

Comment: Here is what i want to achieve (for those not familiar with NetBeans):
https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/how_to_fix_your_use

Comment: `Code | Inspect Code...` (or `Code | Run Inspection by Name...` and choose that particular inspection) and then in a tool window that shows all found notices/errors/hints -- you can use `Alt+Enter` and apply fix for all occurrences (be it current file or whole folder).

Comment: It does not fix class namespaces.

Comment: You are right ... unexpected behaviour (it lists all places but does not allow to use Intention for that -- only manually in each occurrence).

Comment: So, a modern, non-free IDE does not have this core functionality? Really?

Comment: [The Resolving problems support article](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Namespaces+and+PSR+Support+in+PhpStorm) would almost certainly contain the answer if one existed. I suspect it doesn't actually support it.

Comment: Wow, somebody should add this as a feature request.

Comment: requested: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29037

Comment: Also when you moves a file, it doesn't make a change in namespace, and all other references :(

Comment: Heh funny that Netbeans has something that PhpStorm does not :) ... 
+ for Netbeans, but still PhpStorm is the best IDE for PHP .. lol anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you can't do this for a whole file. You are able to import on the fly, as documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/auto-import.html), but not for a pre-existing file. You might consider making a feature request for this.

Answer (score 1):

Its called "Optimize imports" and can be found in menu Code>Optimize imports. You can set keyboard shortcut for that. I have imported keyboard shortcuts from NetBeans so it remained the same, but the functionality is sometimes different than in NetBeans.